# Can my girlfriend move with me to Belgium?

Tags: visa, belgium

Me and my girlfriend come from a non-EU country, we are practically married (living together for two years), but wish not to get married.

I got a job offer at Belgium (postdoctoral position), and I wonder if it would be possible for my girlfriend to get a visa to come live with me at Belgium during the time I work there?

Comment: Which visa are you applying for? This [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_permit_(Belgium)) may help.

Comment: I am actually not sure what visa I am going to get.

Comment: @DavidSegonds My understanding is that it does not matter much in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, under various conditions (having lived together for some time, having sufficient income, accommodation, and health insurance). You must in any case have entered some form of registered partnership but do not need to be married.

[Detailed information on this](http://www.adde.be/J_15/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=211:maj-eu-sejour-limite&catid=216:sejour) (unfortunately only in French). On the face of it, it does sound somewhat difficult. Getting married does help a lot for this kind of things.